# Retrieve all items with a column beginning with specified text on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB:

```
Id: int, hash key
Name: string
```

*(there are many more columns, but I omitted them)*

Typically I just pull out and update items by their Id, and this schema works fine for that.

However, one of the requirements is to have an auto-completing drop down box based on the name. I want to be able to query all items in this DynamoDB table for Name columns starting with a query string.

The SQL way of solving this would be to just add an index on Name and write a query like *SELECT Id FROM table WHERE Name LIKE 'query%'*, but I can't figure out a DynamoDB-friendly way of doing this.

I have considered a few ways to solve this:

1. Scan the table. This is the easiest option, but least efficient. There's a bit more data in this table than I would be comfortable frequently scanning.
2. Scan + cache it in memory. But then I have to worry about cache invalidation etc.
3. Make Name a range key, which supports a **begins_with** function on the query. However, I'd still have to Scan the table since I want to retrieve     results for every single hash key, so this doesn't really work.
4. Make a global secondary index and query it only with the range key. This also doesn't appear to be possible. I could have a column with a static value and use that as the hash key for the GSI, but that seems like a really ugly hack.
5. Use a full text search engine like CloudSearch, but this seems like massive overkill for my use case.

Is there a simple solution to this issue?

Comment: Depending on how many records you have and what you are willing to spend CloudSearch may be overkill, but it is designed to do exactly what you want: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-suggestions.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use case you described is not directly supported by DynamoDB's Query operation today - DynamoDB typically requires you to specify a hashkey then query on the range key accordingly.

However, there is a popular scatter-gather technique that is commonly used for usecase such as yours. In this case, you would add an attribute `bucket_id` and create a global secondary index with `bucket_id` as hash key, and `Name` as the range key.

The bucket_id refers to a fixed range of IDs or numbers, with enough cardinality to ensure your global secondary index is well-distributed. For instance, `bucket_id` could range from 0 to 99. Then when updating your base table, whenever a new entry is added, a random `bucket_id` between 0 and 99 is assigned to it.

During your autocomplete query, the application would send 100 separate queries (scatter) for each bucket_id value (0 to 99) and use `BEGINS_WITH` on the range key Name. After the results are retrieved, the application would have to combine the 100 sets of responses and re-sort as necessary (gather).

The above process may seem a bit cumbersome, but it allows your system/table to scale well by ensuring the load is evenly distributed over a fixed key range. You can increase the bucket_id range as appropriate. To save cost, you can choose to project `KEYS_ONLY` onto your global secondary index, so cost of querying is minimized.

Comment: Do you have any advice for choosing a range for `bucket_id` that has "enough cardinality". Is there some rule of thumb based on the total number of items in the table?

Comment: For your information, here the AWS docomentation on this strategy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that DynamoDB is essentially a key-value store with support for operations against a single key, and you are trying to search all values which doesn't work well . The "simplest" solution to this is to have a known hash key and then you can `Query` it directly and specify conditions.

For example, you could query with `hash_key='name_search'` and `range_key=begins_with(myText)` or `other_key=begins_with(myText)` and get the use case you are describing. This will work fine for small sets of data that do not require a large amount of [provisioned RCUs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html).

The problem is that this does not scale because you are not following any of the [DynamoDB best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html) (in fact, this is an anti-pattern). Take a look at the [*Understand Partition Behavior* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions)

My suggestion would be to use a different service/solution to accomplish this rather than trying to squeeze DynamoDB into this use case.